# Hector SLAM in ROS with RPLidar

Tags: ros, raspberry-pi, lidar

Trying to set up Hector SLAM with the RPLidar A2.  I downloaded both `rplidar_ros-master` and `hector_slam-catkin`; extracted them into my `catkin_ws/src` folder and ran `catkin_make`. Then I edited the `mapping_default.launch file` and changed the next to last line:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser_broadcaster"
 args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser 100" />
```

Then, after running the `roslaunch` command on `rplidar.launch` and on `tutorial.launch`  RVIZ starts but fails to generate a map and gives the warning:

```
No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist
```

Do I need to add the 'map' Fixed Frame to the tf node in my `mapping_default.launch` file?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please add the entire launch script? Looks like some sort of mismatch. First thing I'd check is that the frame name in the line

```
<param name="base_frame" value="/base_frame"/>
```

needs to match the frame name in the line

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_frame laser 100" />
```

Unless you've manually modified your launch script to read base frame as base link, your static transform should also say base frame. As to your last question, /map is already predefined in mapping_default.launch: you shouldn't have to add it again.